# if the scanner found a word not exits in the language, he will stop scanning the rest or will continue and gets tokens?

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, lexer

***c++ syntax***

```
 int x = 5;
```

scanner will gets tokens for this statement

**from**

```
int x = 5;
```

**to**

```
< int>
< x >
< = >
< 5 >
< ; >
```

**what if there a syntax error ?**

```
intd x = 5;
```

he will gets the correct tokens or not?

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a word in the language. But it's a token. Similarly, `intd` is not a word in the language, but it's a token just as much as `x` is. If the language here is C, then:

```c
    int x = 3;
    int intd = 3;
    typedef int intd; intd x = 3;
```

are all valid.

None of this matters to the lexer scanner. The whole point of dividing parsing into lexical analysis and syntactic analysis (which then lead to several rounds of different kinds of semantic analysis and code generation) is to separate concerns. Each component has a clear, limited responsibility, and should never be given unrelated tasks.

The lexical scanner's job is to divide the input into tokens and ignorable whitespace. The tokens are then fed into the parser, whose job is to deduce the syntactic structure of the input. The result of this analysis --often an annotated syntax tree-- is what is used by the subsequent semantic analysis steps.

Which is a long way of saying that the lexical scanner does not know anything about the syntax. It just divides the input into lexical units and lets the rest of the parser do the rest of the work.